# How to productionize XG boost / Decision tree / Random forest model

Tags: r, statistics, random-forest, production, xgboost

I am new to analytics and looking at various ways to productionize the model. Let say for linear regression we can get the equation as y = mx + c which we can use for incoming data and we can take it out of R / SAS/ Python and use it in any of the databases also…

How does it work for XG boost / Decison tree / Random forest if I want to productionize it on the incoming data outside the R / SAS / Python frame work? From where I can get the parameters for the independent variables?

From where do I get the equation to implement?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Decision Tree is the easiest among the three, just if then statement. GB is adaptive in nature. Appears complicated , but scoring code is not complicated. RF is the most troubling, not because its logic, but because the fact a not very complicated RF model can have millions of lines of if-then. Just overhead is killing.

Neither of the three should have any parameters, unlike regression models. They are all essentially TREE. If you need to run them outside of R, P, or S, consider the route of API. I have seen people parsing RF in XML very fast. Depending on delivery requirements, you may or may not need to go micro services. Hope this helps.

Comment: You have taken an unanswered Question with omissions and misconceptions and provided some useful advice.  It is quite terse and open-ended as Answers go, but this is at least in part a reflection of the gaps in the Question.  You get my +1 for some progress.  Ideally the OP will ask for clarifications (making some to the Question in the process) and you will improve the Answer for future Readers.